# Trying to undersand how I can pass arguments from gradle to my shell script?

Tags: variables, command-line, terminal, arguments, gradle

I'm trying to pass command line arguments to my shell script through a gradle task myconfiguration is like this below.

```
task dosomething(type:Exec) {
  workingDir 'dir'
  executable 'sh'
  args '-c','source dosomething.sh $arg'
}
```

And I'm trying to pass it by doing the the following command in the terminal:

```
$ gradle dosomething -Parg=foo
```

And it does not work am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Groovy only performs String interpolation for double-quoted Strings. (That's one of the reasons why I use double quotes by default.) Try:

```
...
args "-c", "source dosomething.sh $arg"
```

Comment: Peter you are the most beautiful person in the whole world thanks so much!